# How to solve problems with Binary Indexed Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-indexed-tree

This question sounds very vague and needs some explanation:

I learned about [Binary Indexed Tree](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/) a few weeks ago. This data structure is a brilliant design. It actually took me very long to figure out how it's built thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWDQJGaN1gY) (I mean... this is the first time I couldn't understand a written documentation and have to watch someone drawing a BIT step by step..)

Anyway, so (I think) I know how to build a BIT and the basic idea behind the structure design.. And now, I'm excited to practise some problems that can be easily solved with BIT.. In fact, someone has gathered a list of nice problems in [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/CodeChef-What-are-some-suggestions-for-problems-where-Binary-Indexed-Tree-BIT-Fenwick-Tree-is-the-primary-concept). I also tried some on HackerRank.

I spent long time trying and only managed to solve two (one by myself, the other taken from other's solution).. For instance, this [direct connections](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/direct-connections) problem..

I realise that the problem is never about how to build a BIT. The real challenge is to conceptualise the problem and use BIT to solve it... this is really beyond my imagination.. **Is there a technique that I can use to tackle such problems?**

And the interesting observation is.. for each problem set, the discussion below contains some comments like:

> "BIT... :)"

It's like whoever managed to solve the problem always ended up with a proud smiley face without further explanation :(

Also, **are there some classical problems that are solved by BIT?**

**EDIT**

For those who voted to close this question: please give a valid reason. I believe this question is worth a discussion here!

Comment: But it depends. Can you choose a *particular* problem?

Comment: @harold how about the direct connections problem I linked in the post... what does it depend on?

Comment: Those who have voted to close this question *have* given a valid reason: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." You're forgetting that Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. If you feel that you need discussion on this topic, I suggest you find a place where such discussion is welcomed. (And no, I have no suggestions as to where that might be.)

Comment: @beaker thanks for the reply. appreciated! I'm afraid that doesn't sound a good reason. I'm not expecting ALL possible answers or the perfect answer (which could be "too long for this format"). I've seen many technical discussions on Stack Overflow. I agree that this question is broad, but "too many" or "too long" answers are definitely not the reason to block a question.